# How to make my bot respond to someone only if it mentions someone specifically?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I wanted to create a bot that reacts to a message that mentions/tags @someone specifically. For example: If @Person1 mentions/tags @Me in the message then the bot should react with an emoji. But if @Person1 mentions/tags any other @People in the message then nothing happens.
Here's what I've tried:

```
import discord
import os

emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} is now active!'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):  

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('@<@666372975062417459>'): #that's my discord id
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)                    #add emoji to message

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `message` you receive as first argument to `on_message` is a message object. It has a [mention property(from documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) attribute that contains list of users or members mentioned. So you can use:

```py
if <user id> in [user.id for user in message.mentions]:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Replace `<user id>` with appropriate user id. `[user.id for user in message.mentions]` converts list of user objects to list of user ids. This method is known as list comprehension. Then the if statement checks if `<user id>` exists in generated list of user ids.
To check that no other people were mentioned use:

```
if len(message.mentions) == 1 and <user id> in [user.id for user in message.mentions]:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Here the first condition checks that only one person is mentioned and the second condition checks that the mentioned user is required user.

Comment: consider adding some more documentation/explanation for some stuff because OP says he is very very very new at programming and python